# ASP.NET Core MVC on Windows IoT (Raspbian Pi)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am new to Windows IoT and am trying to get my first dot net core app running on a Raspberry Pi.
It is not because I think the Raspbian Pi is the perfect place to host web sites, but my ambition is to implement a measurement and control system on the Pi, and make the whole thing accessible through a REST API.
First things first, I wanted to create a standard dot net core app from the VS2017 template and get it running on the Pi.

The template built an App that was available on http://localhost:62100.

As I knew from previous experiments, the app was only listening on localhost, so I modified the Program class as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();
        var hostUrl = configuration["hosturl"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostUrl))
            hostUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:62100";

        return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls(hostUrl)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

And now the server was also usable from my phone using the PC’s IP address.

In order to prepare the project for the Pi, I opened a PowerShell in the folder, where the project file resides (in my case C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AspNetCore\AspNetCore) and ran the command:

```
dotnet publish -r win10arm
```

And then I copied all of the files placed under bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win10-arm\publish to the Pi and start the application from the PowerShell connected to the Pi:

```
  .\AspNetCore.exe
```

The Pi (after some deep thought) answers as when it was run on the PC:

```
  [192.168.200.106]: PS C:\CoreApplications\AspNetCore> .\AspNetCore.exe
  Hosting environment: Production
  Content root path: C:\CoreApplications\AspNetCore
  Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:62100
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But trying to access the server from my browser (http://192.168.200.106:62100) times out with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the version of your windows iot core? And what's the version of DotNetCore you used?

Comment: AspNetCore is 2.0.3, not sure about IoT version (will check when I get back to it) but it is a new download from last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the port to firewall with following cmdlet in powershell,by default ASP.Net Core binds to *http://localhost:5000*.

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ASPNet Core 2 Server Port" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=62100

Comment: I guess you suggest to ad this rule on the Raspberry?
Wouldn't it have been 'actively rejected' instead of timed out, if it was a firewall issue?

Comment: Yes,the reason is that the firewall rejects web request.So you need to add the rule on Raspberry.The information of ***Time Out*** indicates that client can not get the response,but in client ,it does not know whether the server refused the request or it was shutdown.

Comment: Awesome - it was indeed the firewall.